# Get the downloaded file name using java

Tags: java, asp.net, httpurlconnection

I tried to get the downloaded file name using HttpURLConnection, Content-Disposition, but i'm always getting the null value.

- The URL im providing is from the page where the download link is present
- Is there any problem due to dynamically generated **RSID** in URL?
- Is there any other way i can get the downloaded file name?

Below my code :

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.somewebsite.com/emp/Emp_view_rs.aspx?RSID=ezxJzVOJYgZuRiRjmEzZhe==&HighlightWords=.NET%2cASP%2cASP.NET%2cASP%2c.NET%2cASP.NET%2cASP.NET ");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.connect();
String raw = conn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
System.out.println(raw); **//Always getting raw value as NULL**

if (raw != null && raw.indexOf("=") != -1) {
    String[] fileName = raw.split("=");
    for(int g=0;g<=fileName.length;g++)
    {
        System.out.println(fileName[g]);                    
    }
} else {

}
```